# Viewingtext messages and call log on synced phoned via google account

Tags: google, accounts

I have my google account synced on two phones, I want to view my text messages and call log without placing an app on other phone. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Text messages and call logs are related to the SIM being used and have nothing to do with Google account , unlike contacts.

Without using an app to transfer it's not possible